# Computed property's setter isn't invoked when change model property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a field with `v-model="data.field"`, and computed property:

```
data: {
  get() {
    console.log("getting value")
    return this.$store.getters.data
  },
  set(value) {
    console.log("set data " + value)
    this.$store.commit('SET_DATA', value)
  }
```

But this is not working, setter is never called. However, if we change `v-model="data"`, all is working properly.
Example: [codeopen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvbQxX)

Answer (score 1):

Setters are only executed when the variable changed, not when a field inside of them changes. Change your computed property to work directly on the field itself:

```
data: {
    get() {
        console.log("getting value")
        return this.$store.getters.data.field
    },
    set(field) {
        const value = {...this.$store.getters.data, field}
        console.log("set data " + value)
        this.$store.commit('SET_DATA', value)
    }
```

And then change your `v-model` to:

```
v-model="data"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to modify the variable `store` when you should be modifying the `state` instead.

Note: This is for your store `mutations`

Change this:

```
SET_ITEM (state, item) {
  console.log("set item " + item)
  store.item = item
}
```

to:

```
SET_ITEM (state, item) {
  console.log("set item " + item)
  state.item = item
}
```

You should probably also change the other setter as well.

Comment: Where does the `store.item` part come from that you say to change, but is not in the code of the OP?

Comment: @Ferrybig Look at his codepen? His mutation for the store is wrong